# PetitParser: Is there a parser like plus() but with an upper boundary?

Tags: java, petitparser

Is there a parser like plus() that has an upper boundary, to model expressions like `Item <- [a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}`?

Similarly for something like `Item <- [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,5}`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `repeat` operator does that:

```java
Parser item = word().repeat(1, 5);
```

Check the [JavaDoc](https://github.com/petitparser/java-petitparser/blob/c16ef478a4927ac6da48551619d4110758877475/petitparser-core/src/main/java/org/petitparser/parser/Parser.java#L190) for additional information.